# creating tables on remote database

Tags: database, oracle, remote-access

I created a database link using database link.

`create public database link REMOTEDB connect to REMOTEUSER identified by REMOTEPWD using 'REMOTEDB';`

then i create a table in remote db like,

`create table MYTABLE@REMOTEDB (name varchar2(20)));`

It says, `ORA-02021 DDL operations are not allowed on| a remote database..`

Will this Not work on any cost, or am i just missing some permissions to create ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a table through a database link looks like a very bad idea. I cannot see any reason for doing so, therefor i don't think that this can work.

Comment: its not for the usual purpose.. i had to export some data to another datbase (without using usual export/import .dmp) .. anyway, i worked around a little, created tables manually, and inserted datas remotely!

Answer (score 4):

You can call DBMS_SQL remotely to create a table

```
declare
 v_cursor  NUMBER;
 v_ind      number;
begin
 v_cursor := dbms_sql.open_cursor@dblink;
 dbms_sql.parse@dblink(v_cursor, 'create table t_gm_x (id number)', dbms_sql.native);
 v_ind := dbms_sql.execute@dblink( v_cursor );
end;
/
```